# Checkout Order Summary Update Selected Payment Method

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, order-summary

Can anyone help me out to update order summary section of Magento 2?

My goal is to update the order summary with the custom attribute like **'Surcharge Fee'**, when the customer selects any payment method

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Kevin, were you able to solve the problem ? Can you add the answer for fellow users ?

Answer (score 0):

Please go with This  free module.
If required than you can also customize this module

https://github.com/magecomp/magento2-extra-fee/tree/master/app/code/Magecomp/Extrafee

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already tried that once and it only gives additional fee for global, so before customer choose the payment method, the additional fee already shown. What I need is specific fee for specific method and it will be shown when the customer click the payment

Comment: Than i suggest you create a module or you can used this module and customized on basis of payment method
https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_CashOnDelivery

Comment: I already tried to use that one too, and it's to difficult for the admin. Actually I know how to add a fee, and what I need to know is how to update the order summary like reloading the component when we do something like choosing a payment method